# css behaving differently inside and outside lightbox

Tags: jquery, css, facebox

I am making a rails3 app with jquery and facebox.

I am noticing that when I load html inside a lightbox, the CSS styling is different from when I just load the html in a different page. Any ideas why this is happening? The facebox just adds html to the current page which is governed by the stylesheets loaded in the head... so what else could be the cause?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Probably because facebox came with its own css. Use firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox to track down the problem. You "inspect" an element and see all the applied css styles and where each style is defined.

If you can post a link to where this is happening better help can be provided.